# Is this arrangement of Angular Component wrong?

Tags: angular, inheritance, angular-components, angular-content-projection

I've two angular components `Parent` and `Child` and `Child` extends `Parent` component. This is to utilize some common functionality implemented by the parent component.

At the same time `Child` template, refers the `Parent` template through a selector and uses `<ng-content>` to project some content into the `Parent`. `Parent` template provides some common wrapping markup around the child template.

This works fine, although I'm not that comfortable with both the Component class and the template having references to the `Parent` class and template.

Can there be any pitfalls with this kind of arrangement?

Here is an implementation of this. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y5m5fg

Comment: Looking at the stackblitz, it looks like your child is actually a parent, and the parent is a child component.

Comment: This will always be opinion-based. In short, I always try to favor composition over inheritance. When the projects start growing bigger inheritance can be a real pain. You can always place common functionalities in utility classes, services, directives, etc. once a class extends from another, it's hard to "decouple" them in advanced stages of the project.

Comment: @Dino Why do you say that?

Comment: You are calling the child component in `app.component.html`. Then in `child.component.html` you are calling the `<parent>`. That actually makes the child component a parent component, and a parent component a child component. You should rename them.

Comment: @Dino I was naming them based on the inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: I have to admit I've never saw an approach like that. It screams that something will go wrong - this is my opinion. If I were you, I'd rethink the structure for that components. Do you really need to extend the Parent component? Do you really need to call a parent component from a child component? There must be a better way to do this.

Comment: I agree, It doesn't sound right, hence the question here. I agree with @lealceldeiro's opinion favoring composition over inheritance, which I'm inclined to follow.